# How to create 2 Virtual Button in 1 scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to ask how to make 2 virtual buttons at once? I'm really confused about the "(variable name).GetComponent().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);" because I want to make 2 vb. this is my code, please correct me if something is wrong, pls help me, thank you.

```
public class VBManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // private fields to store models
    private GameObject sc_brosur;
    private GameObject sc_video;
    private GameObject btn_1;
    private GameObject btn_2;

    // memanggil scene ketika loaded
    void Start()
    {
        // mencari child dari object ini yang memiliki script VirtualButtonBehaviour
        btn_1 = GameObject.Find("btn_info");
        btn_2 = GameObject.Find("btn_video");

        btn_1.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);
        btn_1.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonReleased(OnButtonReleased);
        btn_2.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);
        btn_2.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonReleased(OnButtonReleased);

        // setelah tracking camera model bisa muncul ketika ditekan
        sc_brosur.SetActive(false);
        sc_video.SetActive(false);
        btn_1.SetActive(true); //vb brosur
        btn_2.SetActive(true); //vb video
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// memanggil objek ketika virtual button ditekan (eksekusi)
    /// </summary>
    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button pressed!");

        switch (vb.VirtualButtonName)
        {
            case "btn_info":
                btn_1.SetActive(true);
                btn_2.SetActive(true);
                sc_video.SetActive(false);
                sc_brosur.SetActive(true);

                break;

            case "btn_video":
                btn_1.SetActive(true);
                btn_2.SetActive(false);
                sc_video.SetActive(true);
                sc_brosur.SetActive(false);

                break;
        }
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button released!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong? What is the question? It seems like you already have two buttons that do two different things according to the name switch ... is something not working as expected? Should in the first case maybe rather be `btn_1.SetActive(false);` ?

Comment: I have a problem when the camera is directed to directly appear the ar object, I mean when the virtual button is pressed it will bring up the object instead of the object immediately appears before pressing. and I'm confused about how to register vb with 2 vb at once, I've seen examples on youtube but mostly use 1 virtual button no more